# Figure between title number and title

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm using `titlesec` package and `\titleformat` command in `display` shape mode. (Unfortunately I am forced to do it, it's the format required for MSc thesis in my university...). The command in my .cls file is:

```
\titleformat{name=\subsection}
[display]
{\penalty -4000\singlespacing\large\arial\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}
{0pt}
{\autolabel}
```

I'm getting some odd results, like, title number and title in different pages and even figures placed between title tumber and the title itself. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: What package implements `\autolabel` or what's its definition?

Comment: The `\penalty-4000` command is quite dubious.

Comment: Without a MWE we can't really help here